# SQL Server stored procedure parameter for IN string in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

Stored procedure `ItemList` has a string parameter for `WHERE` clause `IN` filter:

```
WHERE Item IN (@FilterStr)
```

It works, if the filter is single item only.

```
EXEC ItemList 'ABC'
```

How to call the stored procedure, if multiple items need to be passed for the below SQL `WHERE` clause?

```
WHERE Item IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'HJK')
```

Cannot pass it by 'ABC','DEF','HJK'. Because comma will be parameter separator.  Thanks.

Comment: See the answers this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/629/passing-array-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substituion.  If 2016+ look at string_split()

Comment: Tag you question with the version of SQL Server. See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html.

Comment: Your options are dynamic SQL, [table-valued parameters](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql) in 2008 and above, or [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) in 2016 and above.

Comment: Well, or really bad table-valued functions, I guess.

Comment: Where is that parameter coming from? Pure t-sql does not provide that many options - as Aaron wrote, but if it's coming from a .net client, for instance, it's possible to build the [parameters list dynamically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520435/multiple-ids-in-in-clause-of-sql-query-c-sharp/46521159#46521159)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Isn't Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K or Adam Machanic's CLR function good enough for most cases?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Not when there are better options, IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm referring to pre-2016 environments...

Comment: @ZoharPeled In this specific case, dynamic SQL would be much less complex, and table-valued parameters would be preferable to splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Item is `VARCHAR`. You can try like following.

```
DECLARE @FilterStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FilterStr ='''ABC'',''DEF'',''HJK'''

--Query
WHERE Item IN (
SELECT 
        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Item  
FROM  
    (
    SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@FilterStr, ',', '</M><M>') 
              + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS 
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @parameters nvarchar(100) = '''AAA'',''BBB'',''CCC''';
declare @Query nvarchar(100) = 'select * from [WFL].[TBL_WFTBaseInfo] where 
[wbiEntity] in ('+@parameters+' )';
exec(@query)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.